# How to enable implicit line continuation in VBCodeProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, codedom, vbcodeprovider

The following VB.NET code works when compiled from the Visual Studio:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim source As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    Dim result = From i In source
                 Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Key)
                 Select i.Value

End Sub
```

However, when trying to compile it by using `CodeDom` it appears not use implicit line continuation (I can make it to work by putting underscores but that's exactly what I want to avoid).

The code used:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string vbSource = @"
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim source As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

        Dim result = From i In source
                     Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Key)
                     Select i.Value

    End Sub

End Module
";
            var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v3.5"); // .NET v3.5

            CodeDomProvider codeProvider = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider(providerOptions);

            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");

            CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, vbSource);
        }
```

Comment: If you change the compiler version to 4.0, does it work?  I could be wrong, but I believe the implicit line-continuation feature was not added until VS 2010/.NET 4.0.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, changing to v4.0 does solves it indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling it to use the 3.5 version of the compiler.  Implicit line-continuation was not added as a feature until version 4.0 of the .NET Framework, so you'll need to use the version 4.0 (or later) compiler if you want the implicit line-continuation to work.  Try changing this:

```
providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v3.5"); // .NET v3.5
```

To this:

```
providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0"); // .NET v4.0
```