# How to Use VBCodeProvider

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vbcodeprovider

I am writing a Windows Forms application using .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows 7 x64.

My program needs to be able to compile some text to an EXE. I found out that I could do this with the VBCodeProvider. The problem is, I don't know how to use it, and I have already Google searched and looked at the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have You looked at:
[VBCodeProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.vbcodeprovider.aspx)

Have You tested the example Code.

You can also look at:
[How to enable implicit line continuation in VBCodeProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358055/how-to-enable-implicit-line-continuation-in-vbcodeprovider)